# While inside while php

Tags: php, list, while-loop

We're trying to put a while inside a while loop.
The first while is run through and the results are displayed in a list (139, 140, 141). 
The list for the second while only displays one value (1ste troop).
These are the results: 
139 
1ste troop 
140 
141

So it seems that the second while is only executed once.
What can I do to fix this?

```
echo "<ul>";            
            while($user = $allUsersintroops->fetch_assoc())
            {

                if($user['userid'] == $_SESSION['userid'])
                {   
                    echo "<li>" . $user['troopid'].  " </li>";

                    while ($mytroops = $alltroops->fetch_assoc()) 
                    {
                        if($user['troopid'] == $mytroops['troopid'])
                        {
                            echo "<li>" . $mytroops['description'].  " </li>";
                        }
                    }
                }   
            }           
echo "</ul>";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inner loop stops once `fetch_assoc` returns false... but that indicates the end of all found results and it doesn't have any rows left for the next iteration.

You should collect all the rows from `$alltroops` into an array once, then iterate over that:

```
echo "<ul>";
$allTroopsList = array();
while ($mytroops = $alltroops->fetch_assoc()) {
  $allTroopsList []= $mytroops;
}
while($user = $allUsersintroops->fetch_assoc()) {
  if($user['userid'] == $_SESSION['userid']) {   
    echo "<li>" . $user['troopid'].  " </li>";

    foreach($allTroopsList as $mytroops) {
      if($user['troopid'] == $mytroops['troopid']) {
        echo "<li>" . $mytroops['description'].  " </li>";
      }
    }
  }   
}           
echo "</ul>";
```

Additionally, you should consider adding some filtering to your `$allUsersintroops` query, because you are only using a part of the the returned rows, which means the rest of the rows are sent from the DB to your code for no reason, wasting time and bandwidth.